# How to propagate the trajectory in GMAT with a custom thrust profile

Tags: trajectory, thrust, gmat

So basically I was trying to design a low thrust maneuver to increase the apogee of the spacecraft.

I solved it separately and got some thrust profile (thrust and it's direction as a function of time). Now I want to verify my calculations, that applying that particular thrust leads to the same final orbit as I had predicted.

Can I use GMAT for this purpose?
If yes, then how?

Are there any resources available online?

Comment: Although it's for a different purpose, the procedure discussed in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/46845/12102) might be made to work here, though approximating low continuous thrust as a lot of small impulses is not ideal. There may be better solutions. How do you parameterize your thrust? A lookup table of vectors? An analytical function of time? A constant vector?

Comment: Oh, also see [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12822/12102): "R2015a: GMAT now supports modelling of electric propulsion systems."

Comment: @uhoh thanks for linking to my answer. I also believe that's the best way to solve Aryan's problem. In fact, I've solved a similar problem (low thrust orbit raising for a constellation) before using the Python interface.